# Как проверить сразу все значения массива? Без цикла

Tags: c#

Я делаю бота для ВКонтакте (VKBotFramwork).
Суть моей "проблемы" такая:

```
if (e.Message.FromId == 83647281|| e.Message.FromId == 92715382|| e.Message.FromId == 52810273)
```

Данный if позволяет отдельных лицам по их id пользоваться ботом в беседе.

Можно ли как-то упростить данную проверку? Если вдруг будет 7 человек или ещё больше, то if будет огромен!

Например, засунуть все id в массив и как-то сразу их проверить? Не используя циклы, сразу одной строчкой в if, такое возможно?

```
int[] personID = { 83647281, 92715382, 9182622, 52810273};

if(personID.....)
```

Спасибо за помощь, ребят!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `Enumerable.Contains`:

```cs
int[] personIDs = { 83647281, 92715382, 9182622, 52810273 };
if (personIDs.Contains(e.Message.FromId))
{
    // человеку позволено пользоваться ботом
}
else
{
    // человеку нельзя пользоваться ботом
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!